# Equivalence of iterating over filter and continue condition within iteration

Tags: rust, iterator, closures, immutability, borrow-checker

To keep my code somewhat legible I extracted several data structures into a separate struct:

```rust
struct S {
    x: Vec<i32>,
    y: HashSet<i32>,
    z: Vec<i32>,
}
```

That lives only within one method call and it's subcalls:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut w = S { x: vec![], y: HashSet::new(), z: vec![], };
    do_part_of_the_work(&mut w);
}

fn do_part_of_the_work(w: &mut S) {
    // 1. Works
    for (index, &item) in w.x.iter().enumerate() {
        if w.y.contains(&item) {
            continue;
        }
        w.z[index] += 1;
    }

    // 2. Seems equivalent to 1. but doesn't work
    for (index, &item) in w.x.iter().enumerate()
        .filter(|&(_, &item)| !w.y.contains(&item)) {
        w.z[index] += 1;
    }

    // 3. Seems equivalent to 2. and doesn't work either
    for (index, &item) in w.iter_not_in_y() {
        w.z[index] += 1;
    }
}

impl S {
    fn iter_not_in_y(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, &i32)> {
        self.x.iter().enumerate().filter(move |&(_, &item)| !self.y.contains(&item))
    }
}
```

I'm essentially trying to do what codeblock `1.` does in the form of codeblock `3.`, with `2.` as an intermediate step that doesn't work, although these seem equivalent. Had all attributes of `S` been local variables, it seems that all three code blocks would have worked.

Moving the codeblock inside the `impl` didn't get me far either:

```rust
impl S {
    fn doing_it_inside_the_struct(&mut self) {
        // Doing 3. inside the struct instead, doesn't work either
        for (index, &item) in self.iter_not_in_y() {
            self.z[index] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't block `2.` work? Is it not equivalent to `1.`? Could this problem be avoided by choosing a different design?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1678a63da221d04a22acffb1703e053)

Comment: [Borrow splititng](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with version 2:

```
for (index, &item) in w.x.iter().enumerate()
    .filter(|&(_, &item)| !w.y.contains(&item)) {
    w.z[index] += 1;
}
```

is that the closure for `filter()` captures `w` by reference, that is, it holds a `&w`. This means that the whole `w` is borrowed as long as this closure is alive. Then when you try to mutably borrow `w.z` the compiler fails.

The code in the first version uses the `w.y` and `w.z` in separated borrows and `w` itself is never borrowed, so it works.

The solution is to write the closure to capture only the `w.y` and not the `w`. Unfortunately there is not an easy and nice syntax for that. The nicer I can write is something like:

```
for (index, &item) in w.x.iter().enumerate()
    .filter({
        let y = &w.y;
        move |&(_, &item)| !y.contains(&item)
     }) {
    w.z[index] += 1;
}
```

With the `let y = &w.y;` you capture only the `y`. Now you have to mark the closure as `move` or else you would capture `&y`, and being `y` a temporary that would not work.

The problem with with version 3 is similar: calling a member borrows `self`, that is `&w` so you cannot modify it afterwards. But a similar workaround would not work, because what would happen if your `iter_not_in_y()` implementation used `self.z`? You could easily get to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies. Do you think that borrowck could be expanded in the future to support version 2, perhaps even version `doing_it_inside_the_struct`?

Comment: @vandenheuvel The problem with version 3 is the _local reasoning_ principle, that is that the borrowck should not look the impl. of other functions, only the declaration, and who knows what you do inside a method? Version 2... it is plausible that using `w.y` in a closure would borrow only the member and not the whole struct. Actually I think it would be very nice!

Comment: @vandenheuvel And indeed it is very plausible! https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2229-capture-disjoint-fields.md